# Contar quantidade carrinho de compras

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa noite, preciso contar a quantidade de produtos que estão no carrinho no campo quantidade.

Estou usando PHP PDO e MYSQL

**TABELA**

```
id | quantidade | produto
 1 |     5      |   582
 2 |     8      |   122
```

O total precisa dar **13**, neste código abaixo ele dá **2**

**CODIGO**

```
$stmtCount = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(quantidade) as total FROM carrinho");
$stmtCount->execute();
$resultCount = $stmtCount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="cart-det">
    <?php if(empty($resultCount->total)):?>
        <span class="cart-count">0</span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="cart-count"><?php echo $resultCount->total; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `COUNT` retorna apenas o número de linhas que atendem ao critério da busca. 
O que você precisa usar para somar os valores de uma coluna é o `SUM`.

O seu código então ficaria assim:

```php
$stmtCount = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(quantidade) as total FROM carrinho");
$stmtCount->execute();
$resultCount = $stmtCount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: vlw... deu certinho